# "login details cannot be blank" while posting curl in php

Tags: php, curl, sms, sms-gateway

> This is my code:

```
$senderid = $_POST['senderid'];
$tomsg =  $_POST['mobilenumber'];
$textmsg = $data;


 $url = 'http://global.smsindiahub.in/api/mt/SendSMS?';
$data = [
   'user' => "username",
  'password' => "password",
  'senderid' =>  $senderid,
    'channel' =>  'Normal',
     'DCS' =>  '0',
      'flashsms' =>  '0',
  'number' => $tomsg,
  'text' => $textmsg,

  
  

];

$curl = curl_init($url . '?' . http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [

  'Content-Type: application/problem+json'
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

> This is the Output:

```
  Response: {"ErrorCode":"1","ErrorMessage":"login details cannot be blank",
```

> What am I doing wrong? I've tried eveything but it's just coming back with the same error everytime

Comment: Consult the API documentation. This is not something we can answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the `Content-Type`? `application/problem+json` doesn't look correct, but without further info it is impossible to answer.